# css border shadows errors in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hi I am trying to add a border to button in cshtml

```
.linkbig:hover {
    border: solid #000000 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000 ;
    width: inherit;
}
```

but all I am getting is a border when I want a shadow this is only failing in IE

any help?

Comment: `box-shadow` is the standard CSS property. And all latest browser have support for it. However if targeting an older version then you have to use vendor prefix as well.

Comment: FYI: Box shadow is only supported in IE9 and newer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

box shadow in IE need no prefixing

```
box-shadow: 1em 0.1em 0.5em 0.05em #000000;
```

or older IE you need `-ms`

```
ms-box-shadow: 1em 0.1em 0.5em 0.05em #000000;
```

firefox will need `-Moz`

```
-moz-box-shadow: 1em 0.1em 0.5em 0.05em #000000;
```

if you do not need the border line you need to remove this:

```
border: solid #000000 1px;
```

or you'll end up with a 1px black line around your `.linkbig` and this is likely to hide your shadow if its really subtle.

`-Website` is only supported by Safari, Chrome, Opera.

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-` is only supported by Safari, Chrome, Opera 15+.

Therefore, your code will not work in IE or Firefox.

You could however try using:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;  /* Firefox */
-ms-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;  /* Internet Explorer */
box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000; /* CSS3 */
```

However, this is only supported by IE 9 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like below. So that it will work in chrome, firefox and IE.

```
.linkbig:hover {
border: solid #000000 1px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000 ;
box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000 ;
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;
width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**CSS:**

```
.linkbig:hover {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;
 -o-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  filter:
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=10, Color='#000000')
```